# Loop functionality for overlay google map v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to implement feature of loop in overlay images of clouds, with the help of radar which changes its position with respect to time. How this can be implemented. I am using google map v3.

Comment: Do those clouds have to change shape while moving?  Where do you get the data of those clouds?  Making overlays that move (in time) is possible; no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of overlays, moving in time.  As an example, I let Pac-man chase a ghost over Belgium.

EDIT: I added a start and stop button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Moving overlays</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #directions-panel {
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        width: 390px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      #map-canvas {
        margin-right: 400px;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      var data = [
        {time: '20:00:00', pacman:{lat: 48.8, lng: 4.3}, ghost:{lat: 50.0, lng: 4.0}},
        {time: '20:30:00', pacman:{lat: 49.4, lng: 4.4}, ghost:{lat: 50.2, lng: 4.2}},
        {time: '21:00:00', pacman:{lat: 50.0, lng: 4.5}, ghost:{lat: 50.4, lng: 4.4}},
        {time: '21:30:00', pacman:{lat: 50.6, lng: 4.6}, ghost:{lat: 50.6, lng: 4.6}}
      ];
      var dataCounter = 0;
      var dataInterval = 1000;  // every new frame every 1000ms.  Feel free to change this
      var pacman = null;
      var ghost = null;
      var map;
      var timer;

      function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 7,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 4.5)  // Belgium
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions
        );
      }

      function ghostIcon() {
        return {
          size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
          url: 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_ZEF1cuisJEs/SGsuTtZd5cI/AAAAAAAAANY/iAqmMPQaX7g/s400/red.png'
        };
      }
      function pacmanIcon() {
        return {
          size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
          url: 'http://www.scientix.eu/scientix-2-theme/images/emoticons/pac_man.gif'
        };
      }

      // this function will be called every 1000ms (or what ever dataInterval is).
      function timelapse() {
        var item = data[dataCounter % data.length];  // easiest way to make a loop.  After the last item, item 0 starts again

        if (! ghost) {// if the marker doesn't exist yet, first create it.
          ghost = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.ghost.lat, item.ghost.lng),
            icon: ghostIcon(),
            map: map
          });
        }
        else {
          ghost.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(item.ghost.lat, item.ghost.lng))
        }
        if (! pacman) {// if the marker doesn't exist yet, first create it.
          pacman = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.pacman.lat, item.pacman.lng),
            icon: pacmanIcon(),
            map: map
          });
        }
        else {
          pacman.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(item.pacman.lat, item.pacman.lng))
        }
        dataCounter++;
        timer = setTimeout(timelapse, dataInterval);
      }

      function start_timelapse() {
        clearTimeout(timer);           // if you don't add this, the previous timer is still working, you'll get two parallel timeOuts
        timelapse();
      }

      function stop_timelapse() {
        clearTimeout(timer);           // prevents setTimeout(timelapse, dataInterval); from continuing
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="start" value="Start" onclick="start_timelapse()">
    <input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop" onclick="stop_timelapse()">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If we want play and stop functionality then how it can be implemented. Like if stop button clicked then looping stop and vice versa. In start case data array is not fixed, it should be dynamic. Is it possible?

Comment: I added a start and stop button.  And sure, you can fill this with data that can change any time.  It is not something I can answer in a comment though.  Where does your dynamic data come from?

Comment: Here dynamic data meaning is, i am calling ajax for fetching position of clouds for different different cities according to time, i want to display that positions on overlay. If start button click that animation on and vice versa.

Comment: Emmanuel, I put it's implementation in JSFiddle, but not worked, look https://jsfiddle.net/aupohwv2/

Comment: It looks like this is a problem of jsFiddle.  Look at the source code of the result window.  JsFiddle puts a window.onload=function(){ around the code. This means addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize) is ignored, so initialize is never executed.  Just copy/paste my code to an empty .htm file